# What is a positional argument error in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, process

While installing a software plugin for blender, I get the following error:

```
usr@Dell:~/Desktop$ chmod +x radeon.run
usr@Dell:~/Desktop$ ./radeon.run
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing Radeon ProRender for Blender  100%  
the following arguments are required: blender_path
usage: install.py [-h] [--no-matlib] [-v] [--log-file LOG_FILE]
                  [--distr-dir DISTR_DIR]
                  blender_path
```

I get this error and the process terminates.

From What I understand, I need to append the list of paths listed in the `env`(**this is a command typed in the bash**). Is this the problem? How do I edit/fix it?

Comment: Based on [Where are the Blender program files in Ubuntu 14.04?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30470), it would be something like `$HOME/.config/blender/2.xx` or  `/usr/share/blender/2.xx/` (replace 2.xx by your actual blender version)

Comment: @steeldriver, I didn't understand if this was the answer, I was asking how to append the path into the required place,(__if__ that was the problem). Because, I've unzipped blender into a seperate folder: /home/usr/D_drive

Comment: Well I don't know anything about blender, but it looks like "the required place" is right at the end of the command i.e. `./radeon.run /home/usr/D_drive/blender/2.78` or whatever. I don't see why `env` is relevant at all.

Comment: @steeldriver, That didn't work either,  it says a positional argument, blender_path -- blender distro folder is required.

Comment: This looks to be a problem with the script itself, which might be failing to detect blender. The solution would depend on what `radeon.run` is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide directory path of blender executable file.

```
usr@Dell:~/Desktop$ sudo ./radeon.run  <blender_path>
```

I have my blender executable file in /usr/bin. So that, my blender path will be /usr/bin. Complete command:

```
sudo ./radeon.run /usr/bin
```